# JQuery UI: How to add components on an item select?

Tags: jquery-ui, components

Using JQuery UI (1.10.3) I want to add other widgets dynamically when the selected item of my select component changes. I mean depending on which item is selected by user, I need to change my UI components.

What's the best practice?

Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, can you show what you're trying to do with code? What do you mean by "change my UI components"? Replace an accordion with tabs?

Comment: in fact, I want to replace a set of components(a combination of datepickers, selects, texts) with another set of components, depending on which item the user has selected. the select actually specifies what else the user is required to enter for the web application. is it clear now?

Comment: Call the `destroy` method of the components that are being replaced, and then call the initializer of the components you're adding.

Comment: The thing is I have to get the respective components from server side by Ajax in XML or JSON format. I don't know how to send an Ajax request for components and how to receive and set the data as components.

Comment: You need to show some code demonstrating what you're trying to do. When you say "component" do you mean HTML elements or do you mean libraries of Javascript?

Comment: I mean HTML elements, I'm looking for best practices that's why I don't have any code to show yet.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Though I'm not sure about the best practice, but I found this one very useful and apparently popular:

using jquery load() function you can make an Ajax call and the result which is html is loaded into the selected element. yes on the server side there needs to be a servlet, however in my case it was a struts2 action, generating the response html, according to the sent parameters. for example the selected option of the select element.

**So I didn't find any clean approach avoiding string manipulation in building the html response**. anyway it's cool and I can live with it.

:)